# sudo apt update fail

Tags: networking, apt

when I run $sudo apt update.  It always shows me the "connection timed out" error.At the same time, I can surf on Internet but the mark of net connection condition always gives a "?". How can I fix them?

Comment: The error message usually mention the repository or repositories that failed to connect.

Comment: Please update your with the full output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: @li ma i think it should be sudo apt-get update not sudo apt update

Comment: @GauravGupta `apt` or `apt-get` both work in 16.04 and newer. See `man apt`.

Comment: Are you using a proxy network ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >/etc/resolv.conf
```

or changing the download server in Software & Updates

```
 software-properties-gtk
```

[image]